# Helloworld Example For Loop Trick in Java

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos

I have this code, and i don't understand why the output isn't 4 hello's beside each other.
The answer is just "helloworld"

```
private static void helloWorldExampleTrick() {


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++);{

           System.out.print("helloworld");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Semi colon here `);{` doesn't belong.

Comment: I'm thoroughly disappointed by that 'trick'.

Comment: I agree, i have humbly let you down with my trickyness :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++);
```

the semicolon is a terminator and at the end of the loop, makes it a bodyless loop and despite of having body for your loop, it will only run the iteration of loop ignoring the body.

```
{
  System.out.print("helloworld");
}
```

Here the above block of code will run ignoring whether any iteration run for loop. Even if the loop didn't run once, helloworld will be printed once.

> for(int i=0; i<5; i++);
>   {
>    System.out.print("helloworld");
>   }

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {

       System.out.print("helloworld");

    }

}
```

Notice that there *isn't* a semi-colon (;) after the `for (int i=0; i<5; i++)`.

Having a semi-colon there will only run the code between the `for (int i=0; i<5; i++)` and the `;` on each iteration - ie. nothing.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change`for(int i=0; i<5; i++);{` to `for(int i=0; i<5; i++){`

and here you are the all function

```
    private static void helloWorldExampleTrick() {


        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

               System.out.print("helloworld");

            }

        }
```

and the output after edit is 
 `helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld`

and i suggest to add 
`System.out.print("helloworld"+ "\t");`

it will make your output more readable like

`helloworld  helloworld  helloworld  helloworld  helloworld`